# How to find out the encoder of a video file/stream using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I know how to do that with MediaInfo, it's called 'Writing library' there:

```
Writing library                          : x264 core 146
```

In the above example, the encoder is x264.

Since MediaInfo only work with local file, and I'd like to check the encoder name of hls in some case,  I am wondering is it possible with ffmpeg/ffprobe?

*EDIT*:
Just found that MediaInfo support hls either.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with ffprobe.

```
ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -select_streams v:0 INPUT_PATH |grep 'codec_name'
```

NOTE: This will work if you are using Linux.

Comment: What I want is the information of encoder application, not codec_name. From mediainfo, it's called writing library/writing application.

Comment: You will get the Writing library info only on an encoded video, that means we used some encoder to process encoding. So which indirectly referring us the writing library

Comment: it works in Windows cmd, if use 'findstr' instead of grep:                                        ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -select_streams v:0   test.mp4  | findstr codec_name

Comment: @geo-freak I'm working on an app providing stream service, was tried to figure out which encoder application we used for some old program, the writing library is what I need.